# write a steam to disk in c++ in chunks

Tags: c++, amazon-s3

I am quite new to the C++ world, and I am trying to write a file stream to a disk.I am able to do the following:

```
  const Aws::String objectKey2("filename.tar");
  Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client2;
  Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectRequest object_request2;
  object_request2.SetBucket(bucket_name);
  object_request2.SetKey(objectKey2);
  Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectOutcome get_object_outcome2 =
      s3_client2.GetObject(object_request2);
  auto &retrieved_file2 = get_object_outcome2.GetResult().GetBody();


  std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
  auto myfile = std::fstream("file.tar", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
  myfile.write((char*) &retrieved_file2, 1024*100);
  myfile.close();
```

But this is writing some 1k to disk and the file is unreadable (obviously). The file is a tar from from aws s3, which I try to write to disk in chunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following...

```
auto &retrieved_file2 = get_object_outcome2.GetResult().GetBody();
```

`retrieved_file2` is actually of type `Aws::IOStream &` with [`Aws::IOStream` being typedef'd](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/0.12.9/de/dca/namespace_aws.html#a7fceacd06044b767f90ef1ae53f498d8) via...

```
typedef std::basic_iostream<char, std::char_traits<char>> Aws::IOStream;
```

Hence, you can't simply cast a pointer to `retrieved_file2` to `char *` and hope that the result will make sense when written to a stream.

If the result of the query is the contents of a tar file then you can probably just write the associated `stream_buf` using (untested)...

```
std::fstream myfile("file.tar", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
myfile << retrieved_file2.rdbuf();
```